# 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://wax.greymass.com/v1/chain/abi_json_to_bin

Tags: python

For the transaсtion, I used this construction. Recently it has stopped working. I get an error 404 when calling abi_json_to_bin endpoint with the above, it doesn't seem to accept the json payload list.

```
import eospy.keys
import eospy.cleos
import config


def make_deposit():
    ce = eospy.cleos.Cleos(url="https://wax.greymass.com")
    # ce = eospy.cleos.Cleos(url="https://api.waxsweden.org")
    private_key = eospy.keys.EOSKey(config.API_PR_KEY)
    payload = [
        {
            "args": {
                "from": "wallet1",
                "to": "wallet2",
                "quantity": "1.00000000 WAX",
                "memo": "deposit"
            },
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": [{
                "actor": "wallet1",
                "permission": "active"
                }]
        }
    ]
    data = ce.abi_json_to_bin(payload[0]['account'],payload[0]['name'],payload[0]['args'])
    data = str(data["binargs"])
    actions = [
        {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "wallet1", 
            "permission": "active"
            }],
        "data": data
        }
    ]

    trx = {"actions": actions}
    ce.push_transaction(trx, keys=[private_key])

make_deposit()
```

I replaced the API provider and the code started executing. I think the problem is on the side of greymass and waxsweden

```
ce = eospy.cleos.Cleos(url="https://wax.pink.gg")
```